# Master clutch cylinder seal tears

Tags: clutch

There are tears (destroyed), on my new Wilwood master clutch cylinder piston seal...second Wilwood master clutch cylinder did the same. What can be done?  This is on a Cobra replica.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What are you doing with it when the seal tears? Did you bench bleed your master cylinder before putting it into the car?

Comment: Are you exceeding the normal working stroke? If so, the seal may engage with an opening and then get shredded.

Comment: Have you carefully examined the bore of the master cylinder for defects?